# Customizing the new table after using UISearchbar and filtering

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar

I am using a UISearchBar to search through my table. My problem is, as soon as I search for something, the UISearchBar creates a new tableview as overlay with the search results and this new table is basically without any properties (no background, separator insets, everything white etc.). How can I customize this new table view (make it look like the previous one before). I don't find any function where I can access it to give it properties like e.g. background color or so.

Is there a function I can use for customizing the view? I am using this function that at least the height for the cells are the same:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 90
}
```

The following screenshots describe my problem best.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: y not change  the current tableview background cells instead of adding a new one every search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright found a solution after some hours of trying. The following two functions helped me to also customize the cells of the new table view which is put over my old one. I didn't know about the `willDisplay` function, but it works like it should:

```
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 90
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if(searchActive){
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            tableView.backgroundView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "darkBackground"))
            tableView.separatorStyle = .none
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Update the tableView's background view as follow,

```
tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red()
```

or

```
tableView.backgroundView = UIView()
tableView.backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red()
```

Comment: Well dude that's what I already tried. Problem is that a new table view is going to be created. But I found the solution which uses the `willDisplay` function. Check out my solution!